# onCreate() being called infinitely

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm new to android and I cannot figure out why my onCreate() in my activity is being called over and over.
In my MainActivity I have this function search, that is called when a button is pressed.

```
private void search(View v){
    //Get input fields if null then dont restrict search
    ... 
    ...
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PersonActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("miles",numMiles);
    i.putExtra("min",numMin);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then in my PersonActivity Class I have this onCreate Method.

```
public class PersonActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public ArrayList<PersonInfo> people;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context _context;
public PersonInfoListAdapter _adapter;
public static ListView _list;
public int _position;
private static final String APP_ID = "4cae6e4d7d89bc4b02196b352ae91650";
// Find this in your developer console
private static final String API_KEY = "4A3243EECEA842F7B1FC6E7A4B00DA7A";

public PersonActivity() {}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person);
    View listV = findViewById(R.id.friendList);
    _list = (ListView) listV;
    CMApiCredentials.initialize(APP_ID, API_KEY, getApplicationContext());

    try {
        people = new ArrayList<PersonInfo>();

        Context context = _list.getContext();
        _adapter = new PersonInfoListAdapter(context, people);
        _list.setAdapter(_adapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    _list.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();
            return true;
        }
    });

    Integer numMin = -1;
    Integer numMiles = -1;
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        numMin = extras.getInt("min");
        numMiles = extras.getInt("miles");
        Log.d("Person Activity", "Miles" + numMiles.toString());
    }

    queryForPeople(numMiles, numMin);
}

private void queryForPeople(Integer numMiles, Integer numMin){
    //Get users location
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10, locationListener);
    Location lastKnownLoc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


    double lat = lastKnownLoc.getLatitude();
    double lon = lastKnownLoc.getLongitude();

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PersonActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    //search for friends
    PersonInfo.searchObjects(this, SearchQuery.filter("location").near(lon, lat).within(numMiles, DistanceUnits.mi).searchQuery(),
            new Response.Listener<CMObjectResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(CMObjectResponse response) {
                    List<CMObject> objectList = response.getObjects();
                    for (CMObject o : objectList) {
                        PersonInfo p = (PersonInfo) o;
                        people.add(p);
                        Log.d(TAG, "Person was found: " + p.getName());
                    }

                }
            });

    _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        Toast.makeText(
                getBaseContext(),
                "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                        + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

The problem is this onCreate() in my personActivity is being called over an over. And I cannot figure out why. queryForPeople makes a call to and API that returns information that I use to populate the people ArrayList that is used in the adapter.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Doesn't seem to have anything wrong with it...Try using log statements in both your activities at all the lifecycle functions (and at any other suspicious point in your code) to see the chain of events..It will help you figure out what is happening

Comment: Does your activity extend another custom activity class, or one of the standard ones such as Activity, AppcompatActivity etc? Also, what does queryForPeople do? Is there any startactivity call anywhere else? Do you do something strange in the other lifecycle methods (onStart,  onPause, ...)?

Comment: @JHH They both extend actionBarActivity. queryForPeople just makes a call to an API that returns a bunch of JSON that I convert back to PersonInfo Objects that goes into the People array. That array is then linked with the adapter that is supposed to fill the listview. However, In my logs the call the the API is being done infinitely and the variables numMiles and numMin from my bundle are not being set past the first API call.

Comment: Probably you have some silly mistake somewhere. We've all been there. Your best hope for help is probably to include your entire class for us to study.

Comment: @JHH Ive updated the post to include the entire personActivity class. Please let me know if you see anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Seems to me you're starting the activity with an intent over and over again and the activity launch mode is probably left at default.

You're calling     

"queryForPeople(numMiles, numMin);"

in onCreate and it starts the activity again
"Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, PersonActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);" and there you go back to onCreate() in the new instance of the activity of the same class.

Comment: Well, as I suspected you *do* have a call to startActivity from queryForPeople. So this will indeed be recursive. What is your thinking behind starting "yourself" from the query method?

Comment: Wow. This is what happens when I refactor code horribly. Thanks so much. Sometimes you just need an outside pair of eyes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queryForPeople method calls startActivity on the activity you're already running from. So this will end up being infinitely recursive. I don't see why you would want to start yourself from anywhere in your activity, it just doesn't make sense. Unless you intended something else with those two lines, simply remove them.